# How can I convert the plot to NumPy?

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I want to save a plot (of a polygon that builds via code) to a NumPy (not as an image file), but I don't know how can do it?!

this is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5.12, 5.12))
N = 3
val = np.random.rand(N, 2, 3)
patches = []
for i in range(3):
    patches.append(Polygon(val[:, :, i], True))
p = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.6)
p.set_array(np.array([500,23,1002]))  # assign values
ax.add_collection(p)
fig.colorbar(p)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

and plot of it:
[a plot after run above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3YdT.png)

can anyone tell me, how can I do it?

Comment: What format are you wanting to save the data?

Comment: @t.o.  txt format. even, if you guide me on how to convert it to a NumPy array it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the polygons, you only need to remember the vertices of each polygon. For each shape, and set of vertices, it may be better to save as a dictionary, because these are characteristics of the object which `.json` files are meant to handle.

From the [`docs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html), `Polygon()` has a method that retrieves the vertices for that polygon `.get_xy()` so we can use this to get a tuple of coordinates for each vertex.

The next thing you specified is to be able to save the values assigned within each triangle given by the array that is plugged into `ax.add_collection`. We can move this to the top of the code, and then iterate through the list of values, adding them as values in a dictionary of keys.

Then the code becomes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

import json # To save the dictionary format

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5.12, 5.12))

N = 3
val = np.random.rand(N, 2, 3)
fill = [500,23,1002] # The fill values you want to save
patches = []         # The list to save each triangle object
keys = 'tri'         # The names of each triangle
tri_dict = {}        # Initialize the final dictionary

for i in range(3):
    poly = Polygon(val[:, :, i], True)
    vert = poly.get_xy() # Get the vertices for the Polygon
    patches.append(poly) 
    
    my_dict = { # Create a dictionary of chartacteristics for a single triangle
        'vertices':vert.tolist(),
        'fill': fill[i]
        }
    tri_dict[keys+f'{i}'] = my_dict # For the tiangle name as the key, 
                                    # assign the corresponding values

# print(tri_dict) # To show that you are saving the information of each triangle within 
                  # a dictionary of dictionaries

# Saving the dictionary as .json
jsonString = json.dumps(tri_dict, indent=4)
jsonFile = open(r"<YOUR PATH HERE>\\"+"data.json", "w")
jsonFile.write(jsonString)
jsonFile.close()

# Plot the resulting triangles
p = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.6)
p.set_array(fill) 
ax.add_collection(p)
fig.colorbar(p)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

From here, you should be able to play with the structure to fit your use-case, but for the question asked, this should suffice. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. is there any way to save all of the data including the values of each triangle?
suppose I need to have a matrix with 512*512 dimensions at the end! I fill the triangles with values (in this case [500,203,1002]) and I would like to save all the values inside the triangles (not just vertices).

Comment: yes, maybe it is not the best choice, and using a dictionary is better. 
in this step, something that is important to me is that collect the values that are filled with ```ax.add_collection```. at first, I have three vertices for each triangle but after running the code for example there are 1000 points in each shape. i want to collect this points and values!